# Removing text with regular expression in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Variable string contains lines as

> important 1
> some words ......
> IMPORTANT 34
> some words ......
> **important 99**
> some words ......

The goal is to remove the lines containing the word **important** ignoring their case with a sign **$**. The word important also contains a number. This line may also be in some HTML code such as `<b>important 1</b><br />`

My code so far:

```
<?php
$patterns = '/(important)\s{1,2}\d{1,2}\/';
preg_replace($patterns, '$', $string);
?>
```

Desired output:

```
$ some words ......  
$ some words ......  
$ some words ......
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few notes about the patterns

- You don't need the capture group around important, and add a word boundary `\b` to prevent matching `unimportant`
- `\s` can also match a newline
- If you want to match the rest of the line, you don't have to use the quantifier in`\d{1,2}` as the `.` can also match a digit
- To match the newlines after matching the line, you can use `\R` to get the desired result in the question

You might use

```
^.*\bimportant\h+\d.*\R*
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `.*` Match any char except a newline
- `\bimportant\h+` A word boundary, match `important` and 1+ horizontal whitespace characters
- `\d.*` Match at least a single digit and the rest of the line
- `\R*` Match an optional newline sequence

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ExMjQb/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/b3QXT)

**Example code**

```
$pattern = '/^.*\bimportant\h+\d.*\R*/mi';
$string = 'important 1
some words ......
IMPORTANT 34
some words ......
important 99
some words ......';

$result = preg_replace($pattern, '', $string);

echo $result;
```

**Output**

```
some words ......
some words ......
some words ......
```

---

If you just want to match the whole line and use the `$` to assert the end of the string, you could use:

```
^.*\bimportant\h+\d.*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/w2FPGG/1)

Comment: Good code, but what about adding the $ sign ! Please help.

Comment: @www.friend0.in I have added the pattern ending with a `$` as well.

Comment: I can't see the $ sign :/

Comment: @www.friend0.in The anchor at the end `$` asserts the end of the string `^.*\bimportant\h+\d.*$`

Comment: U got some damn good REGEX knowledge bro, can you please explain the regex a bit !

Comment: @www.friend0.in I have added a breakdown of the pattern.